# In IOS, getting still image from camera and directly put it in the memory, without saving to storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I am developing an interactive camera app on IOS in objective C. I would like to capture a still image from camera and process with my own code(implemented in C++) on the fly. Unfortunately, our IOS guy only knows the APIs to take the shot and save it to dat file, then re-save the dat file into normal image formats. I guess the process of camera->dat->memory or even camera->dat->storage->memory would introduce a lot of delay especially if I would do it at faster rate(say, 10 captures per second).
So, in short, is there any objective-c APIs that I can use to load the camera sensor data into memory that can be accessed by other codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to capture a still image from camera is to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, for example:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    // allow only image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];    // here you have an UIImage in memory

        NSData *photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 1.0);        // here you have the byte buffer for a JPEG
        // OR: NSData *photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture);        // here you have the byte buffer for a PNG

        // do something with picture or photoData
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

}

and then you can use the JPEG or PNG data, no need to write to file